# How to install Linux Mint on a Mac Pro 1,1

Tags: unix, mac-pro

I have a 2006/2007 Mac Pro 1,1 on which I want to install Linux Mint.
As I understand it, the main roadblock to doing so is the fact that the 1,1 has a 32-bit EFI and the Linux distributions no longer include Mac-compatible bootable ISOs.

Research revealed Matt Gadient's *Linux DVD Images* page (https://mattgadient.com/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/). There he provides a number of pre-modded ISOs for various Linux distributions and a program for modifying other ISOs.

I have tried a couple of his pre-modded images and modified a couple others. None of them worked.

Specifically, the Mac recognizes the DVD as bootable media when booting with the Option key held down, but won't actually boot from the DVD when I select it. It accesses it for a few moments and then ejects it and boots from the hard drive with Mac OS on it.

Additional research has indicated that there is a limitation with this approach as well in that this results in an installation that always does a BIOS boot, not EFI and, according to some posts, that disables things like fan control.

So, How do I install Linux Mint with EFI booting on a Mac Pro 1,1?

Hardware:

- Mac Pro 1,1
- Dual-core Xeon at 2.66 GHz (2 processors, 4 cores)
- 4MB L2 cache
- 16GB RAM

Comment: https://securedl.cdn.chip.de/downloads/15467261/linuxmint-19.3-mate-32bit.iso?cdr=4&cid=55964345&platform=chip&1708705716-1708713216-a7273c-B-7d6d5cfa3e7491c09b56e59d081fefac is a 32bit ISO of Linux Mint 19.3 (from https://www.chip.de/downloads/Linux-Mint-Tina-MATE-32-Bit_55964345.html)

Comment: Is that 32-bit Linux or 32-bit boot? I believe that 32-bit-Linux restricts me to 4GB of RAM.

Comment: It might be worth a try just to make sure all the other steps in the installation process work correctly.

Comment: Can you provide links to posts which state BIOS booting disables things like fan control? I wonder about this, because all versions of Windows installed on 2006/2007 Macs were BIOS booting. Would not Windows need fan control?